# where can I find a data set on US's political ideology, i.e. democrats, republicans, socialist, anarchist..etc?

Tags: usa, population, politics

where can I find a data set on the US's political ideology, i.e. democrats, republicans, socialist, anarchist..etc? I need to calculate the percentage of democrats, republicans, libertarian, socialist, anarchist..etc, from the overall US population

Comment: Do you mean party affiliations (registrations)? Many small parties won't have any elected officials, but will have registered members. Do you mean current (2019) or historical trends?

Comment: Yes! pardon for being so vague, I need current data for 2018 or 2019. Party affiliation or registration would be fine. However what about the not so popular like, socialist, libertarians, or anarchist?  Does the US have such parties?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_the_United_States#Minor_parties

Comment: i was going to say....wikidata @philshem